# one git commit persists on every PR. How to clean git commit history?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

For some reason,
When I create a new branch and a new PR I always see tons of previous commits and in addition, my own commit.

When I merge to master and I squash I always see:

- name of an old commit just known as `'merge develop'` (used that a lot of times in the past)
- name of the new commits

So why does this merge develop thing always stays.

How can I clear my commit history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why does this merge develop thing always stay

You probably have commit parents issues: if your branch is based on an old commit of your develop branch, and the following commits have different hashes (squash & merge changes commit hashes), then your PRs will always show previous commits.

Try the following, it should work:

```
# force-sync local develop with remote
git fetch --all
git checkout develop
git reset --hard origin/develop

# new branch
git checkout -b my_branch
# do some commits, push your branch, open a PR, you should be good to go
```